Multiple Table Join Based on Substring
I need to join data from 3 tables (Bill, BillPayment, and BillPaymentLineItem).
BillPayment and BillPaymentLineItem have an easy link as the "Id" field on BillPayment is mirrored in the "BillPaymentId" field on BillPaymentLineItem.
However, the only link from Bill to the other tables is using a field called "LinkedTxn" that contains the Bill ID along with some other data. Thankfully the format is uniform so I can use SUBSTRING("LinkedTxn", 12, 5) to grab the ID.
However, whenever I try to join the Bill I get an ambiguous column error for LinkedTxn.
My current query is:
SELECT Bill.DocNumber, BillPayment.TxnDate, BillPayment.DocNumber, BillPayment.TotalAmt, Amount, BillPaymentID, SUBSTRING("LinkedTxn", 12, 5) AS "BillID"
  FROM BillPaymentLineItem
JOIN BillPayment ON BillPaymentLineItem.BillPaymentId = BillPayment.Id
JOIN Bill ON SUBSTRING(BillPaymentLineItem.LinkedTxn, 12, 5) = Bill.Id

If i remove the reference to "Bill.DocNumber" in line 1 as well as the entirety of line 4 it runs fine. When those are included i get the error "Ambiguous column 'LinkedTxn'" even though i've clearly referenced the table alongside it and that same syntax works in line 1 to display the ID. I've also tried just using "BillID" since I defined it earlier but it says it's unrecognized.
Any help is appreciated.
For reference, I'm using an integration platform to query QuickBooks Online.

Update the line 1 like this SUBSTRING(BillPaymentLineItem.LinkedTxn, 12, 5) AS "BillID", you are using LinkedTxn field, which is present in more than one table, so you have to mention which table you are referring to otherwise the SQL don't know which table you're referring.

Put the table name or table alias before EACH column name you use in your query and you will never get such an error. Currently, you have provided the table name before some of your column names and missed it for others. That doesn't make sense. Furthermore, why do you use double quotes around your column name and your alias? This seems also incorrect.

You can add a prefix before the column names to specify the correct table based on your example. This is needed when you have same column names appearing in more than one table.
I also shorted the prefix with a table alias (using the AS [alias] keyword) for easier typing, but that is optional.
 
SELECT b.DocNumber, 
  p.TxnDate, 
  p.DocNumber, 
  p.TotalAmt, 
  Amount, 
  BillPaymentID, 
  SUBSTRING(li.LinkedTxn, 12, 5) AS BillID -- added prefix
FROM BillPaymentLineItem AS li
JOIN BillPayment AS p 
  ON li.BillPaymentId = p.Id
JOIN Bill AS b 
  ON b.Id = SUBSTRING(li.LinkedTxn, 12, 5)

Note: the performance will likely be slower for a SUBSTRING match than the Id columns. It should be fine if you're searching a small table, but it could be noticable on a large table.

"Can" is too less, you SHOULD add the table name or alias. Before every column you select. You forgot to do so in your answer, so you are on high risk to run in the next issue as soon as someone adds another amount column to one of the affected tables, then you get the same error for the amount column.

The prefixes for the Amount and BillPaymentID were not clear from the example, so I left them out. They should work if they are not also duplicates. But I agree those should also be prefixed. :-)
